# ControlTemplate on Page in WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Does anyone know if it is possible to apply a new style to a Page (i.e. new template)? I created a sub-class of the Page class, set the DefaultStyleKey property and added the new style to Generic.xaml - but it does not seem to have any effect. The OnApplyTemplate method is never called and the new style is not applied.

Class:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyPage);
    }

}
```

XAML (Generic.xaml):

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyPage">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyPage">
                <Border Background="Green" BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Blue">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Obviously, this is just test code to see if its possible, but the style is never loaded. Is it even possible?